# Constant temperature fluctuation for a particular core on an Intel i7-9750H CPU

Tags: windows, cpu, cooling, temperature, core

I have a MSI GE75-9SG laptop with an **Intel i7-9750H** processor and RTX 2080 (non Max-Q) GPU. I just did a clean install of Windows 11 21H2 (Build: 22000.593)

I have Nicehash QuickMiner running for a couple of hours and the GPU is at 100% usage with temperatures in the 70-75 degrees Celcius range.

CPU is idling at around 20-30% usage with temps for all the cores (except one) around 72-80 degrees Celcius. However, there's this one core (Core #2) that's constantly jumping between 70 and 90 degrees Celcius. CPU usage for this core also keeps switching between 10 and 45 percent. The graph looks like this (third from the top - red is the temperature and green is the core usage):

[image: CPU temperature graph]

And here's a close-up GIF of just Core #2:

[image: Core #2 temperature graph]

I used [Core Temp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) for capturing the graphs but it's the same with Task Manager as well:

[image: Task Manager]

Is there a way I can troubleshoot this? If it's a process that's being served by this core, how can I find it? If not, could it be that I need to do a repaste and ensure the thermal paste is spread more evenly? Is this a hardware issue or is it a non-issue?

Comment: Does SpeedFan say the same thing? https://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php

Comment: @Gantendo I didn't try it but I suspect it'll say the same thing because two separate tools (third party tool and a native Windows tool) were showing the same info. Anyway, I fixed the issue. It was caused by **IaStorDataMgrSvc.exe** and I found about it using Process Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cause. It was [**IaStorDataMgrSvc.exe**](https://www.infopackets.com/news/10124/how-fix-iastordatamgrsvc-high-cpu-usage) that was [causing the high CPU usage](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/high-cpu-usage-by-iastordatasvc) (and therefore high temperature) on Core #2. Other cores were also affected but not nearly as much as Core #2 (CPU 4 in my case). As soon as I killed the process, CPU usage and temperature for Core #2 fell off a cliff:

[image: Core #2 usage and temperature]

I used [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find the root cause. I should've tried it out first given how useful and advanced it is but it had skipped my mind. Anyway, here's how I did it:

1. Open **procexp.exe** as Administrator.
2. Click on the **System Information** button (third button from the left) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
   [image: Process Explorer buttons]
3. Navigate to the **CPU** tab in the **System Information** window that pops up
4. Check the **Show one graph per CPU** box at the bottom
5. Hover over the graph of the CPU core that's causing problems to see which process was using that core at that moment
   [image: Process Explorer - processes using Core #2]
6. Kill it with impunity (assuming you know what it does and that killing it won't affect your system... much)

After I did this, the CPU usage/temperature graph for Core #2 looks like this:
[image: Core #2 - temperature issue fixed]

The overall CPU usage and temps for all cores also fell quite a lot and now the CPU usage is around 15% (from around 30% earlier) with temps averaging around 60-65 degrees Celcius:
[image: CPU temps - balance is restored]

Comment: To properly fix the issue, I had to uninstall Intel Rapid Storage Technology so that the associated service which starts IaStorDataMgrSvc.exe is also removed. [Intel RST](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html) seems to speed up access to files on hard drives and SSDs but I'm getting pretty good performance without it so I uninstalled it.

Comment: Real world tests are yet to support Intel's assertions about RST. AHCI should give the same performance.